# Using same entity model from different assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I creating a little modular asp.net MVC application. I am using dynamic entity framework for adding a entity model to dbcontext:

i have a category entity and i want to use this entity in different project in one solution. when i running application i see this error:

```
The type 'Module.Pages.Models.Category' and the type 'Module.Menus.Models.Category' both have the same simple name of 'Category' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model
```

Comment: The error message contains a perfectly reasonable explanation: you can't use two types with the same name in the same model. Rename one or both of your types.

Comment: Entity Framework does not like a "dynamic" setup...

Comment: Thanks, i changing names and see this error:

Comment: The entity types 'Pages_Category' and 'Menus_Category' cannot share table 'Categories' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them